# Conversão de String para Date

Tags: javascript, html, data, conversão-de-tipo

Eu tenho formulário html com o seguinte input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Início:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="inicioEvento" name="inicioEvento" class="form-control input-md" type="datetime-local">
    </div>
</div>
```

O meu problema é fazer a conversão do resultado de formMap.get("inicioEvento"), que retorna uma String e converter para o tipo Date, visto que na classe Evento, o atributo inicio é do tipo Date, logo setInicio(Date inicio).

P.S: sou iniciante.

Comment: Java ou javascript? Não é a mesma coisa, apesar dos nomes parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter uma string em data assim:

```
new Date('2011-04-11')
```

para mais informações: [MDN|Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)